# Nehalem Xeon performance on 32-bit OS, XP vs 2003

Tags: windows, memory, 32-bit, numa, nehalem

I have to run 32-bit code on WinXP or Win2003. Nehalem Xeons (5500 series) should be the fastest, but I'm not sure what'll happen with the memory arrangement. I'm unsure about 2 parts:

1. To get a maximal speed memory setup, I'll need to install at least 6gb of RAM (to give each CPU 3 sticks to work with). Is the memory interleaved in such a way that a 32-bit OS (WinXP or 2003) will get maximum performance out of it? (I'm fine wasting a few gb of RAM).
2. Will Win2003's NUMA support work for the Xeon 5500s? (If so, I presume I should use Win2003 rather than WinXP?)

Answer (score 1):

Why limit your system with a 32-bit OS?  You can run 32-bit code just fine on a 64-bit OS, and 64-bit Server 2003 will run awesomely well on such a system as you describe.  Personally I would go with 2008 or Linux.

Anyway, there is no conceivable reason to run 32-bit OS on a dual Nehalem Xeon.  So get a 64-bit OS and **12 GB** of RAM.

Comment: I'd go with Linux, but for this project I have to use certain 3rd party software/code that's only supported on 32-bit XP & 2003.. and the support is a must.

Comment: Tell this 3rd party to get a move on and provide 64-bit support.  It's been six years now!

Answer (score 0):

**You seem to be confusing quantity of ram with speed of ram.**

Usually you want to go with less quantity of ram that is higher quality rather than quantity of ram ( assuming you have enough ram total ).

More importantly... **How are you using 4GB of RAM?!**

If all the apps you are running need more than 4 GB total you might want to reconsider your approach... but then again to get to that much memory usage means you have already burned a lot of time...

---

Slightly unrelated, regarding Windows XP 32 bit and ram limitations:

[Windows XP 32 bit is limited to 4GB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Microsoft_Windows) ( presumably because it ignores the 4 additional address bits that all new computers come with see [Physical-address-extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension) ).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm worried about the realized speed of memory controllers, not the speed or size of memory. Nehalems have 3x DDR 1333 channels/CPU, so 2 CPUs and min size DIMMs = 3x2 = 6gb min to use all controllers. I just want to know if it'll use the first few 100mb well in that config.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Server 2003 Enterprise is both NUMA-aware and have support for true 36-bit PAE addressing to address up to 64GB (in SP1 and later). So that is the best thing to use.